# NuGet: Should I downgrade my dependencies to maintain compatibility?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard

I maintain a NuGet package targeting `.netstandard 1.1` & `2.0` that has two dependencies, `Newtonsoft.Json` & `System.Value.Tuple`. Up until now I always tried to update those dependencies to the latest version to "support the latest and greatest".

Now, I feel like this might have been counterproductive as I'd like the package to work for as many people as possible. E.g. if someone can't get past `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2` for whatever reason they can't use my NuGet package I guess?

Does it make sense to downgrade to the lowest working version for all dependencies or would I introduce new problems with that approach?

Comment: I'd say it makes sense to do that, if you want to widen support for your package. Then upgrade your minimum version if you discover you need a new feature or bug fix

Comment: Given that there is no .net framework under support that works ONLY with netstandard 1.1 - why would you do this? And why would you FORCE A user to use possibly an older version?

Comment: @TomTom well this is really not what I'm asking about, but netstandard 1.1 support was a legacy requirement and might get removed in the future. But how am I FORCING people to use it when netstandard 2.0 is supported as well?

Comment: Well, everyone else is moving on. You obviously can FORCE people to use your outdated dependencies on newer versions - because SOME acutally change the API (i.e. Automapper, HellLang ProblemDetails) and unless you go with them this means your newer versions block dependencies updates.

Comment: Everyone? as long as Microsoft for example does not update their Surface Hub OS it's not even possible to use any kind of netstandard packages in UWP packages targeted for this. So why should I force people to use newer packages when there's absolutely no technical need? Also, none of the dependencies you mentioned are used in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to support applicable ranges in your package dependencies. Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges) to learn more about how NuGet supports interval notation for specifying version ranges. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution) has reference material on how NuGet resolves package dependencies. Hope this helps.

This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) has some best practices defined for Best practices for the package version.